# mvc editor templates result is cached

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use editor templates with a custom master page so that

```
Html.EditorFor(o => o.Name)
```

generates a label and an input, I also use a custom DisplayName attribute to localize the labels

```
[DisplayNameLocalized("Name")]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

I've put a breakpoint in the attribute's constructor and noticed that it is called only the first time I render the page with the EditorFor on it, so I guess the result of the editorfor is cached, anybody knows how to avoid this caching ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered same problem. This works for me

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageNumber)
        {
            var wishlistModel = new WishlistModel();
            BindGifts(wishlistModel, pageNumber);
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
                return PartialView("_UserGiftList", wishlistModel);
            }

            return View(wishlistModel);
        }
```

After some digging in MVC sources i found that all Html helpers get data from ViewData.ModelState object and on unknown reasons ModelState cached after ajax Request.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you need to use `[NoCache]` attribute on the Action.

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

It is also possible to use `<%@ OutputCache %>` directive in the template - but some complain that it does not always work.

For reference look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx).

You can use `<%@ OutputCache NoStore="true" %>`

Comment: @Aliostad it doesn't help, i tried also simple helpers like @Html.LabelFor, @Html.ValidationMessageFor, they all get cached

Comment: @Aliostad yes tried it, also my request is an ajax request (the ajax response is not cached), in case that matters

Comment: OK, can you do me a favour? Use fiddler and catch ajax call request and response and bring here just the headers. Cheers

Comment: @Aliostad I've just added this in my answer

Comment: This is the request, I need the response.

Comment: Response headers please. We need to check if the no cache being outputed.

Comment: @Aliostad it's Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Comment: OK that proves there is no caching. Something is wrong in there and without full source code i would not be able to tell.

Comment: I found there is a DisplayAttribute which does the job and it is not cached (too bad it's sealed)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when deploying to an Azure Website. An old version of an EditorTemplate was being consistently shown. I tried manually Publishing the cshtml file, I tried FTPing into the site and deleting both the Views folder and the Bin folder; but still this ghost of an EditorTemplate was haunting the site!

What finally worked was checking the **Remove additional files at destination** option under **Build > Publish > Settings > File Publish Options**.